# how to get value hidden in C# when it is set by jquery after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

i am nwe to jquery.how i get value of hidden field after post back in csharp. when ever post back occures value dissapear.
this is my hidden field.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="Hid_BasicSalary" runat="server" />
```

this is jquery code where is assign data to it after succsesful execution of ajax web service.

```
var BasicSalary = $('Hid_BasicSalary');
 BasicSalary.val(data["BasicSalary"]);
```

this is c sharp code when i click on button postback occurs afte this node data.

```
protected void Btn_PIncrementSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TxBx_IncrementAmount.Text = Hid_BasicSalary.Value.ToString();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Utility.Msg_Error(this.Master, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

please help me

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2027062/235710

Comment: use name property. also in c# the name-property defines the "server"-sided fieldname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery we use the selector for select any elements, and we have to put `.` for the class and `#` to the id selector so please put `#` or `.` before your element.

In your case, `$('#Hid_BasicSalary');` or `$('.Hid_BasicSalary');` is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

i was missing # with $.

```
var BasicSalary = $('Hid_BasicSalary');
```

i write this instead of this

```
 var BasicSalary = $('#Hid_BasicSalary');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var BasicSalary = $('#Hid_BasicSalary');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  This code is page load to get new value from hidden

```
Request.Form["hdnvalue"];
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed the "#" and i think that you should use the hidden control's clientid.

```
var BasicSalary = $('#<%=Hid_BasicSalary.ClientID%>');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to get value of server control from javascript/jquery

```
var BasicSalary = document.getElementById('<%=Hid_BasicSalary.ClientID%>').value
```