# Accessing asp:HiddenField in Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

I am very confused when it comes to using asp:hiddenfields .

Here is my code:

`<asp:HiddenField ID ="CurrentAnswer" runat="server" Value="-1" />`

and in a js file loaded in that html page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(document.getElementById("<%= CurrentAnswer.ClientID %>"));
});
```

This value returns null. It will work if i put it into the same asp webform, but not in a separate js file.I have seen this done on just about every page I looked at. [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1799758.aspx) for example. I have no idea why this is not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: CurrentAnswer.ClientID can only be used inside an ASP

Comment: This is explained in detail on this page:
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027062/jquery-hidden-field[/link]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the javascript in sepearate js file, you want to use [Static (or Predictable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) for ID.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="CurrentAnswer" runat="server" Value="-1" 
   ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

### Separate JavaScript File

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert($("#CurrentAnswer").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the CurrentAnswer ID is not dynamic, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert(document.getElementById("CurrentAnswer"));
});
```

Of course, this will give you an object, so you can call .val() to get the value of it.