# Passing .Net control values to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, function

I am attempting to pass different values to a javascript function depending on which button is clicked.

I have two hiddenfields on the page and I want the value of the first field `hidA` to be used when `btnA` is clicked and the second field `hidB` value to be used when `btnB` is clicked.

The value will then be read by javascipt.

**EXAMPLE**

```
onclick="test(22);"
```

However I am unable to read .Net control values without breaking the syntax.

**ASPX**

```
<input id="btnA" type="button" value="A" onclick="test($('#<%= hidA.ClientID%>').val());"/>
<input id="btnB" type="button" value="B" onclick="test($('#<%= hidB.ClientID%>').val());"/>
```

**Jquery**

```
function test(e){
  $('#label').text(e);
}
```

**QUESTION**

How can ASP.NET control values be passed to a javascript function?

Comment: If you're seeing the `<% %>` tags client-side then it's not really a syntax issue, it's that the page isn't being processed by ASP.NET on the server-side at all.  It's just being passed to the client as-is, like standard HTML.  If that's not the case then I may have misread your question, can you clarify?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want the ClientID (actual generated ID from .NET) or do you want "some" ID from code-behind to be used in the DOM?

Comment: The issue using .net controls in this way is that the apostraphes prematurely end the string.

Comment: I have two hiddenfields on the page and I want the value of the first field to be used when button A is clicked and the second field value to be used when button B is clicked.

Comment: @Leon I want to get the value of an asp:hiddenfield.

Comment: In what way is it "breaking the syntax"?

Comment: @JLRishe See image attached above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method of doing this is setting the ClientIDMode to static on the hidden fields and post either 'A' or 'B' in the test variable.  Like this:

```
<input id="btnA" type="button" value="A" onclick="test('A');"/>
```

Then in the test-method you get the value from that hidden control (and not in the call itself):

`$("#hid" + parameterValue).val();`

That's one option. You are however in this way limited to the controls you push to the client. But since you're already creating hidden controls in the original request I don't think this'll be an issue.

Comment: This was the alternative and preferred method I was looking at doing but I ran into a similar problem building up the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `onclick` attribute server-side, e.g.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnA.Attributes.Add("onclick", "test($(" + hidA.ClientID + ").val());");
    btnB.Attributes.Add("onclick", "test($(" + hidB.ClientID + ").val());");                
}
```

provided of course that both `input` elements have `runat` attribute correctly set in the .aspx:

```
<input id="btnA" type="button" value="A" runat="server"  />
<input id="btnB" type="button" value="B" runat="server" />
```

The above sends the following html back to the client:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidA" id="hidA" value="22" />
<input type="hidden" name="hidB" id="hidB" value="33" />        

<input name="btnA" type="button" id="btnA" value="A" onclick="test($(hidA).val());" />
<input name="btnB" type="button" id="btnB" value="B" onclick="test($(hidB).val());" />
```

which I think is the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered moving the click event out of the control?

```
<input id="btnA" type="button" value="A" cssClass="btnA hidBtn" />
<input id="btnB" type="button" value="B" cssClass="btnB hidBtn" />

<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($) {
           $(".btnA").click(function() {
               test($("#<%= hidA.ClientID %>").val());
           });
           $(".btnB").click(function() {
               test($("#<%= hidB.ClientID %>").val());
           });

           // Or you could try something like this
           $(".hidBtn").click(function() {
              var hidId = "#"+this.id.replace("btn","hid");
              test($(hidId).val());
           });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes this is the way I am doing it at the moment but the reality is there are not 2 buttons and two hiddenfields, there are ten. This question arose because I am trying to combine all the click events into one smaller function. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027062/jquery-hidden-field 
You could use the $= selector to look up the value or make the id static as mentioned by Leon.