# How to get field value in page_load event in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created the text box using JavaScript in document.ready function and append with existing custom control using its class name in ASP.Net.

How can I get the text box value in page_load event?

Comment: No, you can't access controls which were created at clientside at serverside. You could use hiddenfields where you store values from these dynamic textboxes. Note that the controls don't exist  at clientside either after the postback.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is no

Comment: @Liam, I will try to disagree, see my answer

Comment: @Liam, I got answer for this question from Andrei "string textBoxValue = Request.Form.GetValues("textBoxName");". This is solvem my problem.

Answer (score 2):

So the control you have created is not a control in ASP.NET sense of things. Strictly speaking, this is just an page element, ASP.NET does not know anything about it.

However if this was a textbox, it apparently became a part of a form, so there is a good chance you can access it's value from the Request object:

```
string textBoxValue = Request.Form.GetValues("textBoxName");
```

Note 1. To have this value in the request, you need to make sure the textbox has `name` attribute set up: `name='textBoxName'`

Note 2. This is definitely not a common or encouraged practice in ASP.NET world. Have you considered manipulating visibility of a server-side textbox?

Comment: No. I don't want to show this text box. Can I set the value using jquery if I using hidden field from ASP.Net?

Comment: @Andrei what about the first time page loads?textbox will not be created until javascript executes

Comment: @user3851503, you can surely set the value of hidden field with jQuery. My answer was for your original question though, which is quite different. If hidden field is what you want, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027062/jquery-hidden-field) for example.

Comment: @shreesha, sorry, i am not sure i understand the question. When page loads first time nothing holds a value apart from what you have set in code behind, and this is definitely not the OPs use case. Then, when page loaded, js is executed, text input is added to the page, and the answer i gave holds valid. Am i missing something here?

Comment: The problem with this is that everything in .net is a postback. so everytime you press a button the page is effectively rebuilt from ViewState, any items added to the form from JavaScript will not be in the ViewState so as soon as you postback you can read the request, when the page returns the page is rebuilt and the input disappears. So this will work once, and once only

Comment: @Andrei, Thanks, If I set the value at jQuery for hidden field value while the document is loading. Can I get the value of a hidden field in page load?

Comment: @Liam, this is mostly true. However if one adds something to the page with javascript, they have to expect this will work only on this page load. So for the immediate question asked this is not the problem but rather an expected behavior.

Comment: @Pranath, yes, since this is a server side control declared on the page this should be as simple as `HiddenField1.Value`